# Render a collection with cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Is it possible to render a collection of partial with a cache array ?

My case :

```
<% cache [ 'favorit', current_user.company ]  do %>
  <%= render 'groups/group', collection: current_user.cached_favgroups %>
<% end %>
```

My cache (UserModel)

```
def cached_favgroups
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "fav_groups"]) {fav_groups.to_a}
end
```